# Xamarin iOS navigation bar image

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

Hi im trying to include a logo into the navigation bar on my iOS app.
The logo has a size of 160x40 and im not using a custom navigation bar.

What I found was solutions to include like a small 40x40 button at the right side, but is there a way to include a larger item on the right side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `UIImageView` to the `UINavigationBar`

```
var navBar = NavigationController.NavigationBar;
var imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("sushiLogo.png"));
imageView.Frame = new CGRect((navBar.Bounds.Width / 5) * 3, 0, imageView.Image.CGImage.Width, navBar.Bounds.Height);
navBar.AddSubview(imageView);
```

[image]

Note: Remember to keep a reference to it and adjust its `Frame` upon device rotation.

Comment: Works except the first line in a custom renderer. You can access NavigationBar there without problems. Thanks!